# (UK) Ex-employer didn't pay out my holiday in-lieu and then flew to Pakistan and stopped replying

Tags: united-kingdom, employer

[It's a continuation of the story started here  a few months ago.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23074/uk-holiday-entitlement-during-first-3-months-aka-probation-period)

After being explained that during the probation period I have still built up a few days of holiday entitlement which should be paid out in-lieu when the company stopped operating, my ex-boss actually admitted she was in the wrong and promised to pay it out soon. (~ £250)

The case involved me and another ex-employee and the second employee got the money soon after but mine never reached me. (Even though I've been sent a corrected payslip and everything)

I've been in contact with the employer to resolve the situation (she has in the mean time moved to Pakistan, or at least claims she did) and she actually told me that there's a chance that she sent the payment to the wrong person and that she will resolve the situation within a week.

Fast forward two months: she's not responding to any of my messages and the payment never reached me.

Citizen Advice Bureau told me that I probably won't see the money since she's moved to Pakistan and UK can't force her to come here.

Actual question: 
Can I do anything to either get the money back or at least report it somewhere so that she'd be on some kind of list or anything that'd make her life harder in the UK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get your money. You could probably go to court and get a judgement against her, which would cause her problems if she wanted to enter the UK again. You would have to pay the cost of all this out of your own pocket. If the person never tries to enter the UK again, it's wasted money. If they try to enter the UK again, it's your decision to decide what revenge is worth to you.

There might be assets left in the UK, for example a pension fund. Again, it will likely cost you more than £250 to get your money back. Sorry.